# Getting rid of FindBugs "Random object created and used only once" when Random is created in the constructor

Tags: java, random, findbugs

I want to get rid of the FindBugs warning "DMI: Random object created and used only once". In the following example, the random number is generated only once upon the object construction. In other terms, for the lifecycle of a single instance of the class `Wrap`, no other instances of `java.util.Random` will be created. Is there a way to get rid of this warning (other than adding an annotation), specifically in the case where `java.util.Random` is instantiated in the constructor ?

```
public final class Wrap {

    /**
     * Random generated double.
     */
    private final double random;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public Wrap() {
        this.random = new Random().nextDouble();
    }

    public Double value() {
        return this.random;
    }

}
```

Comment: Either save the `Random`, or pass it in the `Wrap` *constructor*.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should not create new instances of `Random` every-time your class is instantiated. This is what the FindBugs warning is telling you. [The full warning is](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#DMI_RANDOM_USED_ONLY_ONCE) (emphasis mine):

> This code creates a `java.util.Random` object, uses it to generate one random number, and then discards the `Random` object. **This produces mediocre quality random numbers and is inefficient**. If possible, rewrite the code so that the `Random` object is created once and saved, and each time a new random number is required invoke a method on the existing Random object to obtain it.
>
> If it is important that the generated Random numbers not be guessable, you *must* not create a new Random for each random number; the values are too easily guessable. You should strongly consider using a `java.security.SecureRandom` instead (and avoid allocating a new SecureRandom for each random number needed).

To avoid the warning, there are several possibilies:

- create a constant `Random` in your class

  ```
  private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();
  ```

  that you reuse inside the constructor with

  ```
  this.random = RANDOM.nextDouble();
  ```

  This way, no new instances are created.
- Use [`Math.random()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--) since you effectively want a random double between 0 and 1.
- Use the [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) class with

  ```
  this.random = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(1);
  ```

  that will also return random double between 0 and 1 (exclusive).

Comment: By creating the Random object as a static final field, the warning will be resolved. Thanks Tunaki!